# Unable to pull the upload the loaded data from Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**Unable to pull the dataframe which is uploaded with Tkinter**

```
from tkinter import*
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
a = Tk()
def mfileopen():
    file1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    label1 = Label(text=file1).pack()
    df = pd.read_excel(file1)
    print(df.head())
button = Button(text = 'UPLOAD FILE AND WAIT', width = 30, command = mfileopen).pack()
a.mainloop()
```

**Trying to pull the uploaded data**

```
df.head()
```

**NameError: name 'df' is not defined**

Comment: You only define `df` within the function `mfileopen()`. It won't be accessible outside this function. But it should print the head to the console. If you want to make this variable accessible from outside the function, you will have to work with global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because df is a local variable and you must be accessing it outside the scope of method. You wanna use the global variable

```
df = pd.DataFrame() 
def mfileopen():
    global df
    file1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    label1 = Label(text=file1).pack()
    df = pd.read_excel(file1)

print(df.head())
```